# TYPO3 Plugin nur für Typoscript-Einbindung

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

Ich habe ein Plugin einer Extension dass ich nur über TypoScript einbinden möchte. In der Plugin-Liste des CE-Wizards soll es nicht erscheinen. Ich möchte das dann im Fluid per typoscriptObject Viewhelper laden.

Wie blende ich es im Wizard aus?

Comment: Would be better to ask in english here ;)

Comment: please translate the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not register the plugin in ext_tables.php, thus it will not be shown in frontend. My TS setup for the plugin is:

```html
lib.kofcagents_headerimage = USER
lib.kofcagents_headerimage {
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    extensionName = Agents
    pluginName = pi5
    vendorName = Vendor
    controller = Library
    action = showHeaderImage
    switchableControllerActions {
        Library {
            1 = showHeaderImage
        }
    }
    view < plugin.tx_agents.view
    persistence < plugin.tx_agents.persistence
    settings < plugin.tx_agents.settings
}
```